# How to keep drag preview exactly the same as original item?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

Consider following simplified code for an element that can be dragged

```swift
    HStack {
      Icon(icon: .iconDrag)
      Text("Title")
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(16)
    .onDrag {
      return NSItemProvider(object: id.uuidString as NSString)
    }
```

This results in behavior below, where once drag starts preview element is shown, but it is a fraction of a size from original element and has transparency.

I tried adding `preview : {}` to `onDrag` with same original element duplicate, but it's size is still inaccurate and it has transparency. Is there a way to extend a preview somehow (say with uikit) so that it remains exactly the same as original element? I believe there is a maximum width of preview element at which point it starts shrinking down perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try implementing a custom drag preview by adopting the [`UIDragInteractionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidraginteractiondelegate) in a [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) that wraps your SwiftUI view: by using [`UIDragPreview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidragpreview) and setting the preview provider of the [`UIDragItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidragitem), you can specify a custom view for the preview that will be the same size as the original view and without any transparency.

```bash
+---------------------------------+
| +----+ +-------------------+    |
| |Icon| |Title              |    |
| +----+ +-------------------+    |
| | UIViewRepresentable wrapper   |
| +-------------------------------+
| | UIDragInteractionDelegate     |
+---------------------------------+
   |                                  
   | Custom drag behavior             
   | (UIDragInteractionDelegate)      
   v                                  
+----------------------------------+   
| UIDragPreview (Custom preview)   |   
| Same size, no transparency       |   
+----------------------------------+
```

This is inspired from [`Client/Frontend/TabChrome/TopBar/LocationView/LocationViewTouchHandler.swift`](https://github.com/productinfo/neeva-ios/blob/fe8624ef1b7817806da79b4978b5d53a070b1766/Client/Frontend/TabChrome/TopBar/LocationView/LocationViewTouchHandler.swift#L11)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

// Wrap your SwiftUI view in a UIViewRepresentable
struct DraggableView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIHostingController(rootView: DraggableTextView(text: text)).view!
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: context.coordinator)
        view.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDragInteractionDelegate {
        func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
            let provider = NSItemProvider(object: "Dragged content" as NSString)
            let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
            item.previewProvider = { return UIDragPreview(view: interaction.view!) }
            return [item]
        }
    }
}

// Your original SwiftUI view
struct DraggableTextView: View {
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "hand.point.up.left.fill") // Example icon
            Text(text)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(16)
        .background(Color.gray) // For demo purposes
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DraggableView(text: "Draggable Text")
    }
}
```

The key part in the code which should allow for a "Same size, no transparency" drag preview is the `previewProvider` closure of `UIDragItem`.

```swift
item.previewProvider = { return UIDragPreview(view: interaction.view!) }
```

The `UIDragPreview` initializer is passed the `interaction.view`, which is the UIView that was created by the `UIHostingController` with the SwiftUI view inside of it. Since you are using the original view itself for the preview, it should have the same size as the original.